# Get Sum of Column H based on sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the sum of column H from each individual sheet. The name of the sheet is given in column A

[image]

[image]

The way I have been doing it is using =SUM('BSF10003'!H:H), dragging this formula down and changing the last couple digits manually but this is a long process if there are 100+ columns.

I am new to VBA and am hoping there is a way to do this task quicker

Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

The `INDIRECT` function is another way. Example below,

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'"& A2 &"'!H:H"))
```

A2 = The sheet name

`INDIRECT` lets you make references dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for this! Indirect will be a massive help. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

One way could be a UDF

Paste this in a module

```
Function SumSheets(ByVal SheetName As String) as Double
    SumSheets=Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(SheetName).Range.Columns(8))
End Function
```

And use it like a standard formula...

```
=SumSheets(A1)
```

Will return the sum of column H in the worksheet named in A1

Or as a variation, you could use this along with the UDF.   You'd paste it in the same module like the UDF but you don't need to type the formula.  Instead, you select a cell in a column and run this macro. 
The formulas are added automatically.

```
Sub FillRangeWithSumSheets()
    Dim n As Name: Dim s As String: s = "SumSheetsRange"
    With ActiveWorkbook
        For Each n In .Names
            If n.Name = s Then
                n.Delete
                Exit For
            End If`
        Next
        Set n = .Names.Add(s, "=OFFSET($A1,0," & ActiveCell.Column - 1 & ",COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),1)")
        n.Visible = 1
        Range(s).Formula = "=SumSheets(A1)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: One problem with this is that if the values in H:H of the specified sheet change, the value will not automatically recalculate. To fix this, you could set `Application.Volatile` in your UDF... but then you may as well just use `INDIRECT`.

Comment: @Gravitate Indeed, you're correct about the recalculation. The UDF can be rendered superfluos by simply changing `Range(s).Formula = "=SumSheets(A1)` to `Range(s).Formula = "=Sum(INDIRECT(A1 & ""!H:H""))"`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, will look into this UDF stuff. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @kay23  the power and flexibility of VBA cannot be understated and I absolutely recommend advancing your knowledge.  That said, I do not believe a UDF is your best solution in this particular use case, a standard worksheet formula like the answer provided by Andrew L is your best option.  And while you can do this by modifying my sub  `FillRangeWithSumSheets()` as I described in the comments, there's no compelling reason to do so.  You won't save much time, if any, and a macro cannot be undone, any advantage is completely negated the moment you run the macro with the wrong cell selected.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious 1000% agree, using macros and a bit of basic VBA I have managed to improve our businesses operations 10 fold. I struggle to understand the concept of Dim and declaring the type of variable. Would you be able to recommend the best place to learn all these?

Comment: @kays23 I am obligated to point you to the [bible](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/) but I don't know how helpful it will be. It was practically useless to me when I first started getting serious. Google was my guide and it took me to sites like SO, ozgrid, cpearson, excelmastery, rondebruin and many more.  I can't recommend any one more than any other, in fact, I won't recommend any of them because they are all replaceable. It is far more important to have a challenging project you are passionate about, it will push you deeper than any website is capable of doing!